# Does rostest/gtest (ROS , CPP) provide any conditional compilaton flag?

Tags: ros, rostest, gtest

does rostest/gtest (ROS , CPP) provide any conditional compilaton flag?

My use case is that i have a code snippet using std::chrono::steady_clock to wait for many seconds to enter specific parts of the code i want to test. So I wonder if the is e.g. a #define which is set when a test is compiled so i could exclude some parts of code.

```c
#ifndef ROSTEST
WaitLongTime();
#endif
```

Or is there other way to do it?

Comment: It's generally kind of a bad practice to make your code work differently when it is running a test versus not running a test.  It's hard to prevent other developers from accidentally defining the preprocessor flag and changing the behavior.

Have you considered refactoring you tests and libraries such that you wouldn't have to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line in the CMakeLists.txt does the work:

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_compile_options(-DROSTEST)
  ...
endif()
```